Struggling with Symfony Flex recipes for a new Symfony Bundle
I'm currently struggling to override Symfony Flex recipes locally for testing purposes.
Here's what I've done:

Implemented a Symfony bundle for Symfony  5.4 and up.
Published it on Packagist.
Read the Symfony 6.4 docs: How To Configure and Use Flex Private Recipe Repositories and some other stuff.
Created a private repository and set it up like symfony/recipes or symfony/recipes-contrib, even with the workflows.
Created a recipe and pushed it into my recipe repository like described in the documentation.
Created a new Symfony project from scratch where I can test composer require ... and composer remove ....
Configured the root Symfony project in composer.json to use the private repository endpoint for Flex recipes.
Ran composer update to try out the applied changes. But, my Symfony bundle doesn't seem to pick up the recipe, every time an auto-generated recipe is used.

Could someone please provide guidance?

How to test Symfony Flex recipes locally before adding it to any repository?
How to properly override Symfony Flex recipes and force the usage of the recipes in the private repository?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

After some trial and error, I managed to solve the issue and get my Symfony Flex recipes working locally. Here's what worked for me:

Debugging composer require, remove and recipes:install commands.
Reviewing all files in the recipes repository. The recipe repository index.js was pointing to the wrong URL.
I had to push a 0.1 version of the recipe and tag the bundle repo with 0.x, where x has to be equal or greater than 1.

That was really challenging... I'm seriously thinking about writing completely detailed documentation on the topic, because the official documentation isn't really transparent (rather very opaque, as yivi noted here) and there's hardly any other information about it.
I hope this helps anyone else facing similar challenges. If you have any further questions or need clarification, feel free to ask. Thank you for the assistance!
